# Importing PowerShell module in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, lync

I'm trying to write some C# code to interact with Lync using PowerShell, and I need to import the Lync module before executing the Lync cmdlets. However, my code doesn't seem to import the module and I keep getting a "get-csuser command not found" exception. Here is my code:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(@"import-module Lync");
ps.Invoke();
ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-csuser");
foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Members["Name"].Value);
}
```

Any idea how can I import the Lync module?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got it, the module needs to be imported by its full path, and also the execution policy for both 64-bit powershell and 32-bit powershell need to be set to Unrestricted (or anything other than restricted depending on your case). Here's the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] {"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Lync Server 2010\\Modules\\Lync\\Lync.psd1"} );
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
    runspace.Open();     
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-csuser");

    foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Members["Identity"].Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to use the PowerShell class AddCommand method.

```
ps.AddCommand("import-module Lync");
```

Or you can use the Runspace class, you can find an example here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

Comment: No joy, I've tried that before too. ps.AddCommand("import-module") followed by ps.AddArgument("Lync");

Comment: It only says, that term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. So module should be added another way.