# The term 'Get-CsUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: c#, powershell, lync

I am getting below exception if run lync powershell command "Get-CsUser". I am running application with administrator and on machine which have lync powershell.

> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term
>   'Get-CsUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandInfo(String
>   commandName, CommandOrigin commandOrigin)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandProcessor(String
>   commandName, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, Nullable`1 useLocalScope)
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command.CreateCommandProcessor(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, CommandFactory commandFactory, Boolean addToHistory)
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.CreatePipelineProcessor()
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()

**sample code:**

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial))
{

            //// open it
            runspace.Open();


            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                ps.AddScript("import-module 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft 
                ps.AddCommand("Get-CsUser");
                Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                }
                runspace.Close();
            }
}
```

any suggestion to  fix this ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070747/importing-powershell-module-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but there is a series of 4 articles that describe using Lync powershell cmdlets and C#. For example, here's a link to one of the articles:

[PowerShell Scripting Lync 2010 SDK Using Lync Model API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243705%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

The full set of four articles is published here:

[Lync 2010 Technical Articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228140%28v=office.14%29.aspx)