# Running PowerShell cmdlets in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, office365, powershell-cmdlet

I need to run powershell cmdlets using C# in Visual Studio Console.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string RunScript()
        {

            Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
            Command cmd = new Command("Connect-MsolService"); 
            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
            ICollection results = pipeline.Invoke();  // Here exception occurs
            runSpace.Close();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(RunScript());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code an Exception occurs:

> The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Even though it works when I run the commands in Powershell.

Comment: This error means that most likely module hasn't been imported. Please check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071164/9902555) helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use PowerShell instance, like this:

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });
iss.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage;
var _o365Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
_o365Runspace.Open();
var _o365Shell = PowerShell.Create();
_o365Shell.Runspace = _o365Runspace;
var connect = new Command("Connect-MsolService");
connect.Parameters.Add("Credential", new PSCredential("logon@name",
        GetSecureString("Password"));
_o365Shell.Commands.AddCommand(connect);
// add some msol commands to _o365Shell.Commands as well
_o365Shell.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are executing it as a CMD command, not as a powershell command. 
You have to execute it over an Powershell instance.
Check [executing-powershell-scripts-from-c](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/).

Comment: `You are executing a command prompt, not a powershell command`

Huh?

I'd say the exception mentioned surely came from PowerShell and not a command prompt. It's more likely the module needed hasn't been imported yet.

Comment: The above link is not working and I'm unable to find an equivalent

Comment: Maybe this one might help you: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

Comment: @Afonso "Oops! That page can’t be found."