# Getting particular user details from AzureAD using Powershell cmdlets in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, azure-active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

I am able to import `AzureAD` module and able to connect AzureAD using `Connect-AzureAD` PowerShell cmdlet in `C#`.

When I want to list the users I just simply use the `Get-AzureADUser` got all users.

But When I want to list the particular user using `Get-AzureADUser -SearchString 'user@domain.com'`, I am not able to list.

Tried one:

```
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module AzureAD"); //importing

    //passing credentials
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Username = '"+uname+"'");
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString '"+pwd+"'-AsPlainText -Force");
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password");
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Connect-AzureAD -Credential $LiveCred");


    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser -SearchString 'user@domain.com'");//needed one 

    foreach(PSObject info in pipeline.Invoke())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(info.Members["DisplayName"].Value);//not working
    }
```

Actual `PowerShell` cmdlet:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AzureADUser -SearchString 'user@domain.com'

ObjectId                             DisplayName   UserPrincipalName                     UserType
--------                             -----------   -----------------                     --------
c36eb0fa-2500-4b3f-9499-1852e9ae44fc username user@domain.com Member
```

In case of listing all users, my `c#` code works fine. But In case of a particular user, my `c#` code doesn't work. Where I made a mistake?

For listing all users: // works fine

```
          pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser");            
          var result = pipeline.Invoke();
            for(int i=0;i<result.Count;i++)
            {
                Console.Write(result[i].Members["DisplayName"].Value);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you apparently are searching with the full user UPN, i think it would be better to use the **ObjectID** switch or even try the **Filter** option.

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 'user@domain.com'
```

Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0